# Windows 8.1 Alt-Tab bug in specific programs

Tags: windows-8, alt-tab

Whenever I am in a game of *[League of Legends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Legends)* and I try to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Windows 8.1 generates extra programs that are not open, and if I accidentally select some of them, Windows 8.1 will open them. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The "Other programs" besides Chrome and *League of Legends* are not open. They include "Search Pane", "Skype", and the rest of them have no name, or no action when you tab to them. This only happens when I'm in game, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> functions correctly at all other times.

Comment: What is the process name for these other windows?

Comment: "Search Pane", "Sign into a microsoft account", and the rest have no name. I have none of these open

Comment: Didn't you ask this question on a different account yesterday?

Comment: Yes, and I don't have access to that account (Even though it's pretty much the same)

Comment: It only happens when in this program, no others that I have used have caused this to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I might have your solution:
Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` and delete setting named **AltTabSettings**

It does change the look of the Alt-Tab screen, but I think it's more modern looking.

Just for added knowledge:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> > shows Desktop Applications.
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> > shows Metro Applications

Source: [https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8347f6ce-aceb-41fa-a9a7-e3af04c204ea/unwanted-programs-in-alttab-window?forum=w8itprogeneral)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is also flaky in Windows 10 TP. It was toggling to File in some windows, then stopped one day from actually switching unless I held the keys down and tapped tab again to choose the window I wanted to switch to.

I fixed it so far by making it like Windows XP. Hold the Windows and <kbd>R</kbd> key down together and let go, type regedit and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Navigate to path HKEY_CURRENT_USER \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer, right click in an empty space in the right pane, choose *New* → *Dword*, and name it AltTabSettings. Then right click on it and choose *Modify* and change the *Value* data to 1.

If AltTabSettings was already there, do the last step.

Then restart Windows Explorer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> → Windows processes, right click → *Restart*) or log off and on.

It works as it should and did in Windows XP. Thank God for modifications!