# Change Alt+Tab appearance in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, alt-tab

I have the exact same issue discussed at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/770898/windows-8-1-alt-tab-bug-in-specific-programs) Superuser thread, but the solution is not satisfactory to me.

To recap the problem, I hate the new fancy Alt+Tab interface introduced in Windows 7, and prefer the Windows XP/2000 style. There is a registry hack to get the old Alt+Tab menu to appear in Windows 7, but the menu includes some "phantom" applications (e.g., Search Pane, see pic in thread linked above). I found a way to revert the Alt+Tab behavior on a Windows 7 laptop, AND get those phantom apps to not appear, but that laptop died and I don't remember what I did now. I have a new laptop, but it is Windows 8, and I can make the registry setting to make the old Alt+Tab menu appear, but it includes those "phantom" application windows and I can't get rid of them, like I did before.

Any clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 Alt-Tab bug in specific programs](http://superuser.com/questions/770898/windows-8-1-alt-tab-bug-in-specific-programs)

Comment: @chipperyman, it is not a duplicate.  i even linked to it myself, as a reference.  the solution for it does not apply to me, b/c I want a different Alt+Tab behavior than the poster of that question does.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 8, go to "performance options" and uncheck "Enable Peek" (That's what I see it called in Windows 8.1)
I did this, now when I alt-tab through my apps, the alt tab box stays up as do all the windows as I alt-tab (and shift-alt-tab) my way around.

Hope this solves it for you.

Comment: @ subs, that sounded promising...but to no avail.  i still get the "Search Pane" ghost, plus 3 other un-named ghost apps in the Alt+Tab menu.  I have not logged out and logged back in though.  will try that when I can.

Comment: Any success after the reboot/log-out? I hate that people always say, "reboot".... What worked for me was to kill explorer in task manager and then start it up again. Safer to log out and in, but I was lazy. :)  Pls. upvote me if you found the post useful.

Comment: @ subs, sry so slow, got busy then forgot to get back to you.  i rebooted (well, Windows Update rebooted me, or i would have logged out/in) and I *still* see the Search Pane app...but I don't see the other 3-4 ghost apps yet.  That was just on a quick look this a.m. though - not even sure if it was done "booting".  will be back to confirm my status.

Comment: @ subs, okay, i double-checked, and unfortunately, there is no change.  I unchecked Aero Peek, rebooted, and the search pane is still there, along with 3 un-named ghost apps.  Arggg!

Comment: Sorry that didn't work for you. :|  Remember- If you can't change it in Windows, Microsoft calls it a feature! :)